# How to Split and Sum Members of a String Value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a database column that is a text field, and this text field contains values that look like

```sql
I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121|I=5176;A=77360;D=20181117|I=5087;A=43975;D=20181109
```

and can vary sometimes to look like:

```sql
I=29;A=20009.34;D=20190712;F=300|I=29;A=2259.34;D=20190714;F=300
```

Where 'I' represents the invoice Id, 'A' the invoice amount, 'D' the date in YYYYMMDD format and 'F' the original foreign currency value if the invoice was from a foreign supplier.

I am fetching that column and binding it to a datagrid which has a button labelled "Show Amount". On button click, it fetches the selected row and splits the string to extract "A"

I need to fetch all the sections with A= within the column result... i.e

```sql
A=97920
A=77360
A=43975
```

Then sum them all together and display the result on a label.

I have tried splitting using '|' first, extracting the substring 'A=' then splitting it using ';' to get the amount after "=".

```cs
string cAlloc;
string[] amount;
string InvoiceTotal;
string SupplierAmount;
string BalanceUnpaid;           

DataRowView dv = invoicesDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

if (dv != null)
 {
   cAlloc = dv.Row.ItemArray[7].ToString();
   InvoiceTotal = dv.Row.ItemArray[6].ToString();

    if (invoicesDataGrid.Columns[3].ToString() == "0")
    {
       lblAmount.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
       lblAmount.Content = "No Amount Has Been Paid Out to the Supplier";
    }
    else
    {
       amount = cAlloc.Split('|');

       foreach (string i in amount)
       {
         string toBeSearched = "A=";
         string code = i.Substring(i.IndexOf(toBeSearched) + toBeSearched.Length);
          string[] res = code.Split(';');

          SupplierAmount = res[0];

          float InvTotIncl = float.Parse(InvoiceTotal, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
          float AmountPaid = float.Parse(SupplierAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
          float BalUnpaid = InvTotIncl - AmountPaid;
          BalanceUnpaid = Convert.ToString(BalUnpaid);
          if (BalUnpaid == 0)
          {
            lblAmount.Content = "Amount Paid = " + SupplierAmount + "  No Balance Remaining, Supplier Invoice Paid in Full";
          }
          else if (BalUnpaid < 0)
          {
            lblAmount.Content = "Amount Paid = " + SupplierAmount + "  Supplier Paid an Excess of " + BalanceUnpaid;
          }
          else
          {
            lblAmount.Content = "Amount Paid = " + SupplierAmount + "  You Still Owe the Supplier a Total of " + BalanceUnpaid; ;
           }
         }

}
```

But I am only able to extract A=43975, the very last "A=". Instead of all three, plus I have not figured out how to sum the strings. Somebody help... please.

Comment: [Sum strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18011036/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr thanks, that answers the second part of the question, but the biggest issue is splitting the string and extracting "A="

Comment: Use this method instead, `public int IndexOf (char value, int startIndex, int count);` in a loop and use the result + 1 of the previous call as startIndex, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: Why do you have a column with that input? If I see you saying I=xxx is the Id and so on it creeps me out. Why don't you have one column for each field? I can't see any use case where you would want to have just one column with a string containing ;-separated fields and |-separeted rows ...

Comment: Yeah that's not actually my column. It's a Sage Evolution DB column. Apparently it is supposed to keep track of payments made. I cannot alter it... All I can do is work with it and get chills when I look at it. Just like you :)

Comment: ok well there is weird code out there ;)

Comment: don't I know it :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var in1 = "I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121|I=5176;A=77360;D=20181117|I=5087;A=43975;D=20181109";
var in2 = "I=29;A=20009.34;D=20190712;F=300|I=29;A=2259.34;D=20190714;F=300";
var reg = @"A=(\d+(\.\d+)?)";

Regex.Matches(in1, reg).OfType<Match>().Sum(m => double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
Regex.Matches(in2, reg).OfType<Match>().Sum(m => double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
```

You're doing too much work for something like this. Here's a simpler solution using Regex.

Answer (score 2):

Regex  is prefered solution. Alternatively split, split and split.

```
  var cAlloc = "I=29;A=20009.34;D=20190712;F=300|I=29;A=2259.34;D=20190714;F=300";
  var amount = cAlloc.Split('|');

  decimal sum = 0;
  foreach (string i in amount)
  {
    foreach (var t in i.Split(';'))
    {
      var p = t.Split('=');
      if (p[0] == "A")
      {
        var s = decimal.Parse(p[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        sum += s;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the invoice amount is always located as a second value in the set you can access it directly by index after split:

```
var str = "I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121|I=5176;A=77360;D=20181117|I=5087;A=43975;D=20181109";

var invoices = str.Trim().Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var totalSum = 0M;

foreach (var invoice in invoices)
{
    var invoiceParts = invoice.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var invoiceAmount = decimal.Parse(invoiceParts[1].Trim().Substring(2));

    totalSum += invoiceAmount;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a little more "flexible" solution like this:

```
var str = "I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121|I=5176;A=77360;D=20181117|I=5087;A=43975;D=20181109";

var invoices = str.Trim().Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var totalSum = 0M;

foreach (var invoice in invoices)
{
    var invoiceParts = invoice.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var invoiceAmount = decimal.Parse(invoiceParts.First(ip => ip.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("a=")).Substring(2));

    totalSum += invoiceAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Import the input: "*Deserialisation*"

With the following given input, we have a list of object with property name I,A, and D.

```
var input = "I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121|I=5176;A=77360;D=20181117|I=5087;A=43975;D=20181109";
```

Give this simple class:

```
public class inputClass
{
    public decimal I { get; set; }
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal D { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing it will look like:

```
var inputItems =
        input.Split('|')
            .Select(
                x =>
                x.Split(';')
                 .ToDictionary(
                    y => y.Split('=')[0],
                    y => y.Split('=')[1]
                 )
            )
            .Select(
                x => //Manual parsing from dictionary to inputClass. 
                //If dictionary Key match an object property we could use something more generik.
                new inputClass
                {
                    I = decimal.Parse(x["I"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                    A = decimal.Parse(x["A"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                    D = decimal.Parse(x["D"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                }
            )
            .ToList();
```

It look complexe? lets give the `inputClass` the responsability to initialise it self based on string 
`PropertyName=Value[; PropertyName=Value]` :

```
public inputClass(string input, NumberFormatInfo numberFormat)
{
    var dict = input
                 .Split(';')
                 .ToDictionary(
                    y => y.Split('=')[0],
                    y => y.Split('=')[1]
                 );

    I = decimal.Parse(dict["I"], numberFormat);
    A = decimal.Parse(dict["A"], numberFormat);
    D = decimal.Parse(dict["D"], numberFormat);
}
```

Then the parsing is simple:

```
var inputItems = input.Split('|').Select(x => new inputClass(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
```

Once we have a more useable Structure a List of object We can easly compute Sum, Avg, Max, Min:

```
var sumA = inputItems.Sum(x => x.A);
```

#### Producing the output: "*Serialisation*"

In order to process the input we will define an object like similar to the Input

```
public class outputClass
{
    public decimal I { get; set; }
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal D { get; set; }
    public decimal F { get; set; }
```

The Class should be able to produce the String `PropertyName=Value[; PropertyName=Value]`, :

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"I={I};A={A};D={D};F={F}";
}
```

Then producing and string "serialisation" after computing the ListOutput based on the List input:

```
//process The input into the output.
var outputItems = new List<outputClass>();
foreach (var item in inputItems)
{
    // compute things to be able to create the nex output item
    item.A++;
    outputItems.Add(
            new outputClass { A = item.A, D = item.D, I = item.I, F = 42 }
        );
}           

// "Serialisation" 
var outputString = String.Join("|", outputItems);
```

Online Demo. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VcEQmf

#### Long story short:

- Define a class with the property you will use/display.
- Add a constructor that take a string like `"I=5212;A=97920;D=20181121"`
  nb: the String may contain property that will not be map to the object
- Override the `ToString()`, so It can easly produce it's serialisation.
  nb: Property and value that are not stored in the object will not be in the serialisation result.

Now You simply have to split on your line/object separator `"|"` and you are ready to go using real object, not having to care about that weird string anymore.

---

PS:
There was a little missunderstand about your 2 type of inputs, I mentally saw them as input, output. Dont mind those name. It can be the same class. It doens't change anything in this answer.